# Selenium browser starting twice when using a custom attribute for an Xunit test

Tags: selenium, .net-core, xunit

Created a custom attribute so that I can run different browsers without duplicating the test but when I run the test a browser opens before the test starts and then again when the test begins. Why is this happening?

When I remove the code that starts the webdriver, then no browser start.
When the webdriver is created in the test class then it works fine.

The test method

```cs
[Theory]
[Browser("Chrome")]
public void TestName(IWebDriver driver)
{
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_baseUrl);
}
```

The custom attribute

```cs
public class BrowserAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    string _browser;
    IWebDriver _driver;

    public BrowserAttribute(string browser)
    {
        _browser = browser;
        _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"some path");
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        return new List<IWebDriver[]> { new[] { _driver } };
    }
}
```

I'm expecting only one browser to open but am getting two.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of your code and step through and watch when the browsers are started. Now you know where they are being created and maybe how/where to fix it.

Comment: I've tried this but it seems to be missing the breakpoint. I only have those two files (the test file and the browser attribute.